# Ant Design Collapse shrinks when all panels closed

Tags: reactjs, antd

The collapse component shrinks when i close all panels, but stretches to full length when i open a panel:

[image: closed]

[image: open]

is there a way I can ensure the width of the collapse is same when panels = closed?

https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-dew-h11t1n?file=/src/pages/experiments.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your App in a Row and then give the Col length of your component 24 which is the max size. https://ant.design/components/grid/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party, but in case anybody else comes looking...
The easiest solution would be to simply set the collapse's width to a static value.

For inline styles, it would look something like this:

```
<Collapse style={{ width: "50%" }}>
```

This will ensure that the collapse's width always remains static (half of it's parent's width, for example), regardless of whether it is open or not.